# Which is more important in choosing a PhD programme: institution or advisor?

Tags: phd, application

Short and simple question: as a prospective PhD student, should I consider applying to universities which aren't as good/prestigious (still top 500 worldwide, for instance) in my area, in order to study with a *professor* who is well-renowned, or should I try for better standing *universities*, but study with potentially young and less established professors?

I struggle especially because, often, there is a single (if that) professor in my area in most universities, so it's really a case of individual versus institution.

If it helps, I'm going for a PhD in pure math, but the questions seems independent of the area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related:  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d (and further posts linked therefrom)

Comment: What are your (potential) goals after your PhD and in which country do you intend to pursue them?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I intend to pursue a career as a professor of mathematics at some university (I’m not sure if that’s what people call “tenure track”), hopefully in Europe, although I’m still unsure about that.

Comment: Since this question is closed, I left my answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/202512/125334).

Comment: @Michael_1812, thank you! Not sure why the question was closed - it’s undoubtably related to the linked questions, but none of them involve the importance of the supervisor, which is what I really wanted

Comment: Your title was about the institution rather than the supervisor. I would recommend using the search feature if you want questions more specifically addressing choice of supervisor. Added one more possible duplicate, too.

Comment: [What's more important in choosing a PhD program, advisor or institution?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/44440/17254) does address the topic more directly, but there may be some caveats about how applicable the answers are to mathematics.